# Android id's conflict

Tags: android

I'm having a trouble which i can't solve...

The problem is that when i execute the default code it works just once. If i press the button one more time it displays the second button info properly but the first one gets null. Any idea?

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){

        case R.id.save:

            if (et.getText() !=null && thumbnail != null){              
                 TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                 ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
                 TextView view2 = new TextView(this);
                 Button view3 = new Button(this);
                 view3.setOnClickListener(this);
                 titulo = new String[500];
                 mensaje = new String[500];
                 fotos = new Bitmap[500];
                 view3.setId(i);
                 view.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                 view.setPadding(1, 5, 0, 0);
                 view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                 titulo[i]=""+et.getText();
                 mensaje[i]=""+et1.getText();
                 fotos[i]=thumbnail;     
                 view2.setText(titulo[i] + "       "+view3.getId()+"       "+ i+"       "+ dateFormat.format(c.getTime()) );
                 view2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                 view2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                 i++;

                 view3.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                 view3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                 tr.addView(view, metrics.widthPixels/3, 150);
                 tr.addView(view2, metrics.widthPixels/2, 100);
                 tr.addView(view3, metrics.widthPixels/6, 20);
                 tl.addView (tr, 0);                     
                 final Toast toastMensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Tu entrada se cargó correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toastMensaje.show();
                    et.setText("");
                    et1.setText("");
                    i1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{       
                final Toast toastMensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Tienes que añadir un título y una foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toastMensaje.show();
            }
        break;

        case R.id.photo:

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

        break;

        case R.id.gallery:

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TFRequestCodes);

        break;

        default:    
                Toast toastMensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        titulo[arg0.getId()], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toastMensaje.show();
                /*
                Intent i = new Intent(Second.this, Display.class);
                i.putExtra("titulo", titulo[index]);
                i.putExtra("mensaje", mensaje[index]);
                startActivity(i);*/

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the execution order of this code? What is `i` and where is it set? What is the expected behavior (what should the code do)?

Comment: The problem was a RE-definition of the buttons. Solved